# Unknown notation/omega

Tags: functions, notation, ordinals

What does the 3rd term in $\omega\times\omega\times\omega^{\operatorname*{\omega}\limits_{\smile}}$ with semicircle below the last $\omega$ in definitions 5.3.6
[here](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9807172) mean?

Comment: Not that I want to be adversarial, but is this download link fully legal? (Honest question)

Comment: I've just came across it with the hope that it is. I do not know. I may delete after having obtained an answer.

Comment: Not going to download a file to my computer. Take a screenshot and upload it.

Comment: I've replaced your link with one to the (legal) arxiv version.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Wonderful, that way we even have the $\LaTeX$ source for the mysterious symbol!

Comment: For those interested, the latex code is "_{\smile}."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On p.4 ("0. Introduction", subsection "0.2 Notation"), you have in item 6.

> The collection of all *finite partial* functions from $\omega$ to $X$ is $X^{\operatorname*{\omega}\limits_{\smile}}$.

Comment: +1: *always check the notation section first*.

Comment: I have checked that notation part of the paper many times, but my eye has never hit this symbol.